# Need help for the slider to work In Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

Hi All I have created a small shiny app and i am using slider for the FY Quarter. But when i am getting error when trying to use the slider.

I am using reactive to get the slider update but i am getting error message.
Warning: Error in seq.default: 'from' must be a finite number

Data part

```
Quarter <- c("Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1")
QuarterInNum <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
RiskTierDesc <- c("Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal")
Freq <- c(447,52,1161,470,87,1277,556,69,1284,471,61,1195,481,46,1247,519,46,1641,598,61,1591,556,56,1451,478,41,1617)
FreqPercent <- c(27,3,70,26,5,70,29,4,67,27,4,69,27,3,70,24,2,74,27,3,71,27,3,70,22,2,76)

Data <- data.frame(Quarter,QuarterInNum,RiskTierDesc,Freq,FreqPercent)
```

UI Part

```
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu( 
    sliderTextInput("Quarter","Select Quarter:",
                    choices =  c("FY17Q1","FY17Q2","FY17Q3","FY17Q4","FY18Q1","FY18Q2"),
                    selected =  c("FY17Q2","FY18Q1")))),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tableOutput('table')

    )))
```

SERVER Part

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  dataInput <- reactive({
    #dataframe <- GroupFreq
    qfrom <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[1], Data$Quarter)]
    qto <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[2], Data$Quarter)]
    test <- Data[Data$QuarterInNum %in% seq(from=qfrom,to=qto),]
    #print(test)
    test()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(dataInput())
  #output$table <- renderTable(Data) # to test if i am getting the table 

}


runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```

My expected result is to get the table for the quarter i am selecting in the slider.

Please let me know if there any other detail required. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a couple of things:

1. Your dataframe has quarters in the format "Fy..." while your range picker has quarters in the format "FY...".
2. Your code is comparing the numeric factor level of the quarter field with your text from the range picker.

These two issues are combining to cause your issue. Updated code:

```
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

Quarter <- c("Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1")
QuarterInNum <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
RiskTierDesc <- c("Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal")
Freq <- c(447,52,1161,470,87,1277,556,69,1284,471,61,1195,481,46,1247,519,46,1641,598,61,1591,556,56,1451,478,41,1617)
FreqPercent <- c(27,3,70,26,5,70,29,4,67,27,4,69,27,3,70,24,2,74,27,3,71,27,3,70,22,2,76)

Data <- data.frame(Quarter,QuarterInNum,RiskTierDesc,Freq,FreqPercent)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu( 
      sliderTextInput("Quarter","Select Quarter:",
                      choices =   c("Fy17Q1","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q4","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q2"),
                      selected =  c("Fy17Q2","Fy18Q1")))),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tableOutput('table')

    )))

server <- function(input, output) {


  dataInput <- reactive({
    #dataframe <- GroupFreq
    qfrom <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[1], as.character(Data$Quarter))]
    qto <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[2], as.character(Data$Quarter))]
    test <- Data[Data$QuarterInNum %in% seq(from=qfrom,to=qto),]
    print(test)
    #test()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(dataInput())
  #output$table <- renderTable(Data) # to test if i am getting the table 

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```